# Permutation using ArrayList<Integer> to print by size of 10 in a console

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer, permutation

I wrote simple code on random permutation between 1 to 10 using ArrayList. How can I make ArrayList in my file SmartPermutationGenerator to print the result by size of 10 in a console to get output as below:

I don't want this output:

Random arrays using Smart Force:

8 4 8 1 8 4 10 8 4 1 7 8 4 1 10 5 8 4 1 10 7 2 8 4 1 10 7 5 9 8 4 1 10 7 5 2 6 8 4 1 10 7 5 2 9 3 8 4 1 10 7 5 2 9 6

I want this output instead:

Random arrays using Smart Force:

8 4 8 1 8 4 10 8 4 1
7 8 4 1 10 5 8 4 1 10
7 2 8 4 1 10 7 5 9 8
4 1 10 7 5 2 6 8 4 1
10 7 5 2 9 3 8 4 1 10
7 5 2 9 6

Should limit the solution using arraylist only, don't want to use recursion.

This is my file SmartPermutationGenerator

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Random; 

public class SmartPermutationGenerator
{
    private int size; 
    private Random rand = new Random(); 

    public SmartPermutationGenerator()
    { 
        this.size = 10;
    } 

    public ArrayList nextPermutation() 
    { 
        ArrayList<Integer> unused = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // loop for element in array
        { 
            unused.add(i + 1);  
        } 

        ArrayList<Integer> perm = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) //loop for random number between 1 to 10
        { 
            int pos = rand.nextInt(unused.size()); 
            perm.add(unused.get(pos)); 
            unused.remove(pos); 
            System.out.print(perm.get(k) + " ");

            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            { 
                System.out.print(perm.get(j) + " "); //loop for permutation 10 times
                //System.out.println();
            }
        } 
    return perm; 
    }

}
```

This is my file BrutePermutationGenerator

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BrutePermutationGenerator
{
    private int[] num = new int[10];

    public int[] nextPermutation()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)//loop for permutation 10 times
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//loop for random number between 1 to 10
            {
                int low = 1;
                int high = 10;
                int range = high - low + 1;
                int r = rand.nextInt(range);
                num[i] = num[r];
                num[r] = i;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)// loop for element in array
            { 
                System.out.print(num[i] + 1 + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    return num;
    } 
}
```

This is my main file PermutationGeneratorViewer

```
public class PermutationGeneratorViewer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BrutePermutationGenerator brute = new BrutePermutationGenerator();
        SmartPermutationGenerator smart = new SmartPermutationGenerator();

        System.out.println("\n" + "Random arrays using Brute Force: ");
        brute.nextPermutation();

        System.out.println("\n" + "Random arrays using Smart Force: ");
        smart.nextPermutation();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another excellent solution is to create function for permutation to be repeated in file SmartPermutationGenerator as below:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getRandomPermutation() 
{
ArrayList<Integer> unused = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
.
}

public void nextPermutation()
{
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) //loop for permutation 10 times
    {
    for(Integer item : getRandomPermutation()) 
        {
        System.out.print(item + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Solution credited to Mr.Soleh Abd Wahab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulus operator (%) in the printing loops to see if the index is a multiple of ten. If it is, print a newline.
Something like this would work:

```
for(...){
    System.out.print(...);
    if(count%10==0 && count!=0){ // if the index of the number is a multiple of 10 but not the first number
        System.out.println(); // print a newline to separate rows
    }
}
```

This will add a newline after the 10th, 20th, 30th, etc. numbers.

Comment: i tried this but it not successful. i do find that count++ is not increment in the loop because it detect total of only 1 for each count++, my code as below:

    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    { 
    int count = 0;
    count++;
      
    System.out.print(perm.get(j) + " "); //loop for permutation 10 times
    if (count%10 == 0 && count !=0)
    {
    System.out.println();
    }
    //System.out.print("c : " + k + " ");
    }

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. `count` should be declared at the beginning of your function and incremented each time a number is printed.

Comment: Very nice..successfully get the output that i want.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) so everyone can see that it solved your question. Doing so also gives you and the answerer some reputation.